# reference for harmonically convex functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request, convex-analysis

I am studying harmonically convex function, is there a good reference that summarizes its properties examples operation that preserves it etc.

In particular I have a convex function that is decreasing, through simulation I came to know that it is harmonically convex but need to verify that analytically.
Take for instance $$f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}, ~~ x>0$$ You can see that this function is decreasing and convex and harmonically convex as well.
The function in mind is much more complicated, so it is good idea if I know more about this type of convexity.

Thanks

Comment: Where did you come across this term?

Comment: see for instance https://arxiv.org/pdf/1303.6089.pdf

Comment: What is your "more complicated" function which you're planning to test?